# Conway's Game of Life C++ Code check

Tags: c++

I'll start by saying that I'm a begginer. I've started learning 2 weeks ago. Today I found some video on YT about this Conway's Game of Life. With things I've learned so far I tought I'll give it a go. So I've made this(code below). It doesn't work like it should be and I'm out of ideas why. Could someone check this code below and tell me what's wrong? I don't want a complete solution, just a tip what I should check.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    bool positions[50][50], new_positions[50][50];
    int neighbours=0;

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        for(int x=0; x<50; x++) positions[i][x]=false;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        for(int x=0; x<50; x++) new_positions[i][x]=false;
    }

    //This is some patterns i've put manually into array just for testing, 
    //they should "be alive" at least for 3-4 cycles    
    positions[5][5]=true;
    positions[5][6]=true;
    positions[5][7]=true;
    positions[6][5]=true;
    positions[5][8]=true;
    positions[5][9]=true;
    positions[5][10]=true;
    positions[5][11]=true;

    positions[5][5]=true;
    positions[6][5]=true;
    positions[7][5]=true;
    positions[5][6]=true;
    positions[8][5]=true;
    positions[5][7]=true;
    positions[6][8]=true;
    positions[7][9]=true;
    positions[8][10]=true;
    positions[9][5]=true;


    positions[11][11]=true;
    positions[11][12]=true;
    positions[12][11]=true;
    positions[12][12]=true;


    while(!(kbhit())) {

        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++) {
                for(int pozX=x-1, pozI=i-1; pozI<=i+1; pozX++) {
                    //if(pozX!=x && pozI!=i) {      //this "if" doesn't work, don't know why                
                        if(pozX>=0 && pozX<50 && pozI>=0 && pozI<50) {
                            if(positions[pozI][pozX]==true) neighbours++;
                        }
                    //}
                    if(pozX==x+1) {
                        pozX=x-1;
                        pozI++;
                    }
                }
                if(neighbours==1) neighbours=0;//had to use this instead of previously mentioned if
                if(positions[i][x]==true) {
                    if((neighbours>3) || (neighbours<2)) new_positions[i][x]=false;
                }
                if(positions[i][x]==false && neighbours==3) new_positions[i][x]=true;
                neighbours=0;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++) {
                if(new_positions[i][x]==true) cout << "X";
                else cout << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++) positions[i][x]=false; //clears all cells
        }

        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++) positions[i][x]=new_positions[i][x]; //sets cell status from this cycle, I know I could do this in one loop, but it is more clear to me this way
        }

        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++) new_positions[i][x]=false; //clears this cycle "buffor"
        }   

        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what you were expecting to happen and what you get instead. Also, you should make an effort to minimize the program while retaining the problem, to help us realize what's broken.

Comment: If I had time to use a debugger, I could tell you the issues.  Could you use a debugger for me and edit your post with the results?

Comment: Don't use `if (something==true)` and `if (something==false)`. Use `if (something)` and `if (!something)`.

Comment: Use nested loops for `pozX` and `posI`, instead of trying to do them in the same loop.

Comment: Your method of not counting the cell as a neighbor of itself is wrong. You can just subtract 1 from `neighbours` when `positions[x][i]` is true.

Comment: Your code clears all new_positions each time through the loop and then if position=true it checks for neighbours - if there are <2 or >3 it reclears new_position but it never does anything if the position should stay alive.  The bit that makes new cells when there are 3 neighbours looks right.

Comment: BTW, using X and I is confusing. Usually we call the two axes on a grid X and Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I debugged the code was by using https://www.onlinegdb.com/
Learning to use a debugger is really valuable...

What I have done includes:

- I removed the kbhit() test and the Sleep() call and cls because I am not using a windows compiler.  You will have to put those back if you use my code.
- I changed the bit that displays the board to give it line numbers and to display something in the blank cells and I changed it to avoid calling endl to flush the buffer for every single line.
- I changed the way neighbours were calculated.  I think you were subtracting 1 to take care of the extra add that was done - I think it is better to just use an if statement to avoid adding it in the first place.  Here is my version:

  ```
              int neighbours=0;
              for(int pozI=i-1; pozI<=i+1; pozI++)
                  for(int pozX=x-1; pozX<=x+1; pozX++)
                      if(pozX!=x || pozI!=i) // don't check position[i][x]
                          if(pozX>=0 && pozX<50 && pozI>=0 && pozI<50)
                              if(positions[pozI][pozX]==true)
                                  neighbours++;
  ```
- I changed the way the new board was calculated.  You weren't ever setting the new position to true if it should stay alive.  Here is my version:

  ```
          // set the new board
          new_positions[i][x]=false;
          if(positions[i][x]==true)
              if(neighbours==2 || neighbours==3)
                  new_positions[i][x]=true; // staying alive
          if(positions[i][x]==false)
              if(neighbours==3)
                  new_positions[i][x]=true; // being born
  ```

What I have not done includes:

- There are a lot of stylistic issues and whether they are changed is debateable depending on what you consider best practice.  Things like the variable names and having everything in main() and having a global `using namespace std;` and using a C style array instead of a std::array are all things that we could argue about but that belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com so I haven't changed any of that.

Here is the full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    bool positions[50][50], new_positions[50][50];

    // clear the board
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
        for(int x=0; x<50; x++)
            positions[i][x]=false;

    //This is some patterns i've put manually into array just for testing, 
    //they should "be alive" at least for 3-4 cycles    
    positions[5][5]=true;
    positions[5][6]=true;
    positions[5][7]=true;
    positions[6][5]=true;
    positions[5][8]=true;
    positions[5][9]=true;
    positions[5][10]=true;
    positions[5][11]=true;

    positions[5][5]=true;
    positions[6][5]=true;
    positions[7][5]=true;
    positions[5][6]=true;
    positions[8][5]=true;
    positions[5][7]=true;
    positions[6][8]=true;
    positions[7][9]=true;
    positions[8][10]=true;
    positions[9][5]=true;

    positions[11][11]=true;
    positions[11][12]=true;
    positions[12][11]=true;
    positions[12][12]=true;

    // print the initial board
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        cout << setw(4) << i << setw(1) << " ";
        for(int x=0; x<50; x++)
            cout << (positions[i][x]==true?"X":".");
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int steps=0; steps<15; steps++) {
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++) {

                // count the neighbours
                int neighbours=0;
                for(int pozI=i-1; pozI<=i+1; pozI++)
                    for(int pozX=x-1; pozX<=x+1; pozX++)
                        if(pozX!=x || pozI!=i) // don't check position[i][x]
                            if(pozX>=0 && pozX<50 && pozI>=0 && pozI<50)
                                if(positions[pozI][pozX]==true)
                                    neighbours++;

                // set the new board
                new_positions[i][x]=false;
                if(positions[i][x]==true)
                    if(neighbours==2 || neighbours==3)
                        new_positions[i][x]=true; // staying alive
                if(positions[i][x]==false)
                    if(neighbours==3)
                        new_positions[i][x]=true; // being born
            }
        }

        // print the old board and the new one
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            cout << setw(4) << i << setw(1) << " ";
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++)
                cout << (positions[i][x]==true?"X":".");
            cout << "    ";
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++)
                cout << (new_positions[i][x]==true?"X":".");
            cout << "\n";
        }
        cout << endl;

        // save the generation
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
            for(int x=0; x<50; x++)
                positions[i][x]=new_positions[i][x];
    }

    // print the final board
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        cout << setw(4) << i << setw(1) << " ";
        for(int x=0; x<50; x++)
            cout << (positions[i][x]==true?"X":".");
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your in-deepth answer. I actually manged to solve it myself yesterday. Step by step printing every change and analyzing what is wrong. It took me few hours ;s
I need to start using debugger as you suggested. There was two main issues: one was if statment that was supose to check if current position is diffrent from current analized cell so it won't cout itself as neighbour.
I should have used OR instead AND. The second issue, as you mentioned, I din't check if cell should stay alive, so in next loop they all would reset.
Again;thank you for your answer it was very helpful.